# GCloud App Engine old instances still running

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We've build few services on Google App Engine, we've ship them into production and everything worked as expected. But now I have little issue with one of my integration service which runs on flexible environment. I've deployed serveral times new version and maybe some of deploys wasn't successfully finshed or something like that. Now I see in Stack Driver logging some error logs from running instances of some old version (by version id in "resource" property). It made me few problems with with some version "missmatch" in integration tasks. I don't see this old versions in GC CLI SDK or in web dashboard. I've tried to delete whole service and redeploy it, but after first deploy, there are still new log entries in Stack Driver. I've changed DB credentials to prevent older versions to make mess in DB ¯_(ツ)_/¯. Production environment now runs OK, but there are still some old services spamming logging with errors about DB auth. I cant find this old versioned instances anywhere except this new log entries. Is it normal behaviour? Do you have some tips?

Comment: i'm noticing the same thing myself. It just started yesterday when i deleted a service yet it's still running and i can confirm it by looking at the logs.

Comment: likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835329/app-engine-flex-service-is-running-but-it-cannot-be-found