# App Engine Flex service is running but it cannot be found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How do I shutdown an App Engine Flex service that I already deleted and cannot access?

Yesterday I deployed a new App Engine Flex service which I then deleted. For whatever reason the service is still running a day later. I can confirm by looking at the logs viewer that it's still running and generating logs.

When I go to the GCP console, it doesn't show the service, or a version or an instance of it running, yet it's definitely running.

It's as if there's an orphaned instance running.

Comment: Sometimes the instances don't get killed when you delete a service because some requests are still pending. Normally after some time (maybe 24 hours, depending on the scaling settings),  the requests timeout and the instance gets killed. Since it's been some time since you posted the question, can you confirm that the instance has already been killed?

Comment: @TasosZG It finally shut itself down this morning after 6 days.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It's been quite a few days now.

Comment: We're also experiencing this issue with app engine for Ruby.
It is pretty annoying because it exhausts our 3rd party api quotas and messes up the background job processing.

related topic: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/RNtQq2tjdU0

Answer (score 1):

To kill a Google App Engine you should go into the settings menu and select `disable application`.

You can take a look into the [Managing GCP Projects, App Engine Applications, and Billing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/#disabling_an_application) Documentation.

Also, you can take a look at this [Cleaning up](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/cleaning-up#disabling_your_application) documentation if you want to see more related information.